# Проблема в Buffer с русскими буквами

Tags: javascript, node.js

Массива кода  символов был составлен через этот он-лайн сервис:
http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html

```
new Buffer([1055, 1088, 1080, 1074, 1077, 1090, 32, 1052, 1080, 1088], 'utf-8').toString()
```

Но этот возвращает странные символы: @825B 8@

```
new Buffer('Привет Мир', 'utf-8').toString()
```

Это возвращает нормальный текст: Привет Мир

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы buf.toString() вернул нормальный русский текст, а передача данных в Buffer было именно как массив кода символов?

Comment: Может коды не те? Вот я табличку нашёл http://i.voenmeh.ru/kafi5/Kam.loc/inform/UTF-8.htm

Comment: Во-первых, синтаксис `new Buffer(...)` является deprecated начиная уже с 6 ноды. Во-вторых, во всех версиях оно принимает массив **байт**, а не целых чисел, соответственно, все Ваши "1055" урезаются до байта.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы подсказать, как лучше сделать?

Comment: Ну и да, коды Вы нашли не те. Символу "П", например, в UTF-8 соответствуют байты `0xd0 0x9f` (или `208 159` в десятичной записи).

Comment: Ну вот так и записываете каждый символ набором соответствующих байт: `let buf = Buffer.from([208,159,209,128,208,184,208,178,208,181,209,130,32,208,156,208,184,209,128])`

Comment: Как вы перевели строковое значение в этот нормальный рабочий массив?
> [208,159,209,128,208,184,208,178,208,181,209,130,32,208,156,208,184,209,128]

Comment: Элементарно: `Array.from(Buffer.from('Привет Мир'))+''`

Comment: Ну и еще вариант, без буфера: `String.fromCharCode(1055, 1088, 1080, 1074, 1077, 1090, 32, 1052, 1080, 1088)`.

Comment: Я еще на хабре нашёл. Тоже рабочий.
https://gist.github.com/lihnux/2aa4a6f5a9170974f6aa#gistcomment-2763620

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Как Вам плюсик поставить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, синтаксис `new Buffer()` является deprecated начиная уже с 6 ноды, актуальным является вариант `Buffer.from()`.

Во-вторых, во всех версиях он принимает массив байт, а не целых чисел, соответственно, все Ваши "1055" урезаются до байта.

В-третьих, коды Unicode и коды UTF-8 - это разные вещи. По [ссылке](http://i.voenmeh.ru/kafi5/Kam.loc/inform/UTF-8.htm) от @AlexSazonov можно увидеть, как из первых получаются вторые.

Соответственно, чтобы получить буфер, соответствующий нужной строке, надо сформировать массив, содержащий именно UTF-8-коды символов этой строки (для строки "Привет Мир", это будет `[208,159,209,128,208,184,208,178,208,181,209,130,32,208,156,208,184,209,128]`, где `208, 159` - это два байта, соответствующие символу "П", `209, 128` - символу "р" и т.д.). Как-то так:

```
Buffer.from([208,159,209,128,208,184,208,178,208,181,209,130,32,208,156,208,184,209,128]).toString(); // Привет Мир
```

К тому же, если в итоге Вам нужен не буфер, а таки строка, то можно и вовсе обойтись без буфера:

```
String.fromCharCode(1055, 1088, 1080, 1074, 1077, 1090, 32, 1052, 1080, 1088); // Привет Мир
```

Тут в качестве параметров метода `fromCharCode` надо передавать уже Unicode-коды символов.

Поскольку количество параметров `fromCharCode` является переменным, программно формировать вызов может показаться проблематичным, но тут поможет [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
let codes = [1055, 1088, 1080, 1074, 1077, 1090, 32, 1052, 1080, 1088];
String.fromCharCode(...codes); // Привет Мир
```